# Why isn't my HTML page loading completely?

Tags: html, css, dns

I recently started my first HTML project with the help of Youtube. I'm a beginner and only saw the basics of Javascript in college.

Just finished writing my HTML project and wanted to upload it for free using Google Drive and drv.tw.

The only problem is that certain images and icons do not load (irregularly) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrWvy.png)and/or the pages on the navigation bar take too long to switch.

My question would be, is it because of the free domain or did I do something wrong in HTML?

When I open the HTML file in Safari everything works fine.

Since I'm new to the community, I don't know exactly what and how much I have to upload to get help. So have mercy on me :'D.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for more information on what is needed. You should have been presented with this information as you asked this question.

Answer (score -3):

To help troubleshoot, use your browsers "developer" (F12) mode. Look at the Network view to see why the images aren't displayed. For example: It might be "not found", "not authorized", or other reasons.

From your comment, it would appear that at times the page is rendering before the images are available to display or something else is limiting image files from being presented at all.

Once we know why the browser can't display the images, then the cause can be addressed.

Post the .html  .js and .css code

Please update your question and show the folder structure. It should look something like:

-site-
|
-js
-css
-images

Copy and paste in the code below the folder structure and list the images and their size.

I am not familiar with google drive's capabilities.

It is important to use a web host. There are plenty of free or low cost sites available, so I won't go into it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The images are correctly localized. The only problem is that the images are not loaded constantly. Sometimes it shows up and sometimes it doesn't. I have seen through several Youtube videos that it is possible to successfully host websites using Google Drive features.

The HTML code is relatively easy to write. The site does not have to be able to do much. Give out information with a few pictures and contact details. How can I post the files here? Can I upload the file or copy and paste the code?